# HP Netbook - Cracked screen, accessing bios, external monitor?

Tags: bios, display, netbook

I have an HP netbook with a cracked screen. It boots into Windows fine. I am using an external monitor. I need to access the bios but the netbook doesn't post to the monitor until the welcome screen is loading.

How can I access the bios with an external monitor?

Comment: pound the F keys, one of them opens bios :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigating BIOS by Braille can be fun.

If you know what you're looking for in the BIOS you can find a manual on the HP support (http://support.hp.com) website which'll give you steps to get there in the BIOS, then just follow those instructions pretending you're blind.

Even better, if you know someone with the same type of system, you should be able to boot them side-by-side and do exactly the same thing on both systems, just pressing F10 at the end of the process on your laptop to save the changes, and ESC on the other system so as not to mess them up.

Comment: You're a brave soul lol...I think I'm just going to take a shot at replacing the LCD before I do anything else.

Comment: It comes with the territory. People have come to me for support of the oddest things done to their computers and sometimes it's fun doing things like BIOS by Braille. For a while IBM/Lenovo had an online demo of all their BIOS versions that acted exactly the same as the real thing, making BIOS by Braille for their systems quite easy, relatively speaking.