# How can I access the BIOS menu when I only have an external monitor connected to my laptop?

Tags: laptop, display, multiple-monitors, bios, external-display

How can I access the bios menu when I only have an external monitor connected to my Asus N750JK-T4069H laptop?

I tried the following:

- Put magnets on the laptop so it would think the lid is closed.
- Tried switching screens with the Fn + F4 button on my Asus laptop.
- Uninstall screen through windows menu.
- Disconnected the screen from the motherboard.
- Took out the RAM to see whether the CMOS battery was under there. No success.

As a last resort I was trying to reset the BIOS by taking out the CMOS battery, but I can't find the CMOS battery.

[image]

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/393755/hp-netbook-cracked-screen-accessing-bios-external-monitor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HP Netbook - Cracked screen, accessing bios, external monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/393755/hp-netbook-cracked-screen-accessing-bios-external-monitor)

Comment: Well that states going through the bios blind.... Hooking up a screen would be way easier because I am not even certain if I am in the bios!

Comment: Some laptops dont ever show the BIOS on external monitors. What's the issue with the laptop itself?

Comment: I want to install Ubuntu to replace my current Windows setup. Don't want dual boot so I have to install it from a USB from within BIOS mode.

Comment: " I have to install it from a USB from within BIOS mode. "  Never heard of that, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Ubuntu bootable USB to fully replace Windows. 

I eventually got into the BIOS by getting another monitor which had the same LVDS cable. I could connect it to the motherboard directly and navigate the BIOS that way.

Super annoying that the BIOS cannot be switched to a secondary display easily. Thank you for the help!